# How to use record separator as delimiter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use the record separator (`0x1E`) as the separator in the Pandas read_table() function, but it is instead it seems to be splitting on `\n` (`0x0A`).

This is my code:

```
df = pandas.read_table( "separator.log", sep = "[\x1E]", engine = 'python' )
print( df )
```

This is my input file (separator.log):

```
{
"a": 1
}{
"b": 2
}{
"c": 3
}
```

The record separator is after each closing brace, but may not show up in your browser.

The output looks like this:

```
           {
"a": 1      
}          {
"b": 2  None
}          {
"c": 3  None
}       None
```

When I try

```
df = pandas.read_table( "separator.log", sep = chr(0x1E), engine = 'python' )
```

the error `'' expected after '"'` is given.  Inside the first `''` is the record separator character, but it does not show up in the S/O editor.

Is there a way to force `read_table` to use 0x1E for the delimiter?

Comment: Try just `sep = "\x1E"`

Comment: `sep` is used to set the delimiter for the column not for the row/line.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That returns `'' expected after '"'` for the line with a record separator.

Comment: @Perplexabot Why doesn't it create a new record when it encounters the separator character?  It displays them on the same line, but "full justified" to the width of the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to separate records/lines on `\x1e` (or `chr(30)`).

`sep` is used to seperate/delimate the columns of the table and `lineterminator` is used to seperate/delimate the rows of the table.

Try:

```
pd.read_table("separator.log", lineterminator=chr(30))
```